# How to create this chart using Stata?

Tags: graph, stata

I am working on reproducing the paper ["Motivated Numeracy and Enlightened Self-Government"](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2319992) by Kahan et al. (2017). I am struggling to create the following chart by using Stata (Figure 8 on paper).

My first thought of reproducing this chart is the boxplot, but it does not seem to be working.

I also looked up [Stata's resource](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/graphics/gph/stata-graphs/) for creating graphs, but I did not see anything similar to this one. My next plan in creating this chart is using point estimates and their confidence intervals (I do not think it will give me the exact graph I want).

Please share with me if you have any idea how to create this chart.

[image: Kahan et al. (2017)]

Comment: I don't know how you're searching, but `twoway scatter` for the point estimates or summaries and `twoway rcap` for the intervals is a natural combination. We need to see data example and an ideally an attempt at code.

Comment: I think your are looking for COEFPLOT command: http://repec.sowi.unibe.ch/stata/coefplot/getting-started.html

Comment: @NickCox Hi Nick. Thanks again for your response. My impression of the scatter plot is that the data should scatter around the graph (not the line with confidence interval like this). That's why I did not think of this option. Thanks for shedding light on this. I will have a look at the combination of these two functions and come up with a code.

Comment: @cremorna Thank you for your response. It looks helpful for the chart I tried to create!